VBA Auto Highlight
I tried to auto highlight the cells.
I have 2 worksheets in my excel file, so when there is a value in Sheet1!L2:L1001 it will be highlighted in red color if the value is not same as the cell Sheet2!C2:C7338, what vba code should i use?

Shouldn't you just use simple conditional formatting for this?

As @BigBen said, conditional formatting can do this.  Something like =ISNUMBER(XMATCH($L2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$7338))

@BigBen it will be highlighted in red color but if there is the same value as in Sheet2!C2:C7338, what I need is the opposite, if the value in the cell is not the same as that in Sheet2!C2:C7338 then it will be highlighted.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook it will be highlighted in red color but if there is the same value as in Sheet2!C2:C7338, what I need is the opposite, if the value in the cell is not the same as that in Sheet2!C2:C7338 then it will be highlighted.

I've succeeded with conditional formatting. I used the formula below:
=AND(COUNTIF(Area!$C$2:$C$7338,L2)=0,ISBLANK(L2)=FALSE)

